# Number of updated columns and not rows

Tags: mysql

1 **row** was updated using the following update statement.

But how do I know if only 1 **column** was updated or more than one and which one?

```
mysql> select * from table1;
+------+------+--------+
| pid  | name | city   |
+------+------+--------+
|    1 | aa   | delhi  | 
|    2 | bb   | delhi  | 
|    3 | cc   | mumbai | 
|    4 | abc  | mumbai | 
+------+------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update table1 set city='pune', name='salman' where pid = 4;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: Why you need such functionality? In an update query you are the who decides how may columns should be updated and which.

Comment: Can I ask you what you want to achieve with this?

Comment: AFAIK MySQL won't give you this information. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visually you could check by running your select again, but I don't think you want that.

One way would be to store a history of changes and use some sort of flag for the current row. so you would do an select of the current row, and update of the current row to deprecate it, then an insert of a new row with all the data.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will overwrite the results, even if column values are the same. It doesn't check whether the current and new column value are the same, it simply does what you tell it to - since you're the one who decides what's getting updated.

Comment: @Micahel: This is wrong according to MySQL docs: *"If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this and does not update it."* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html